# How to trace back this compiling error?

Tags: java, eclipse, mahout

I am learning to use mahout by starting with a example copied from the book. However, the eclipse compiler gives me the following message:

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel.<clinit>(FileDataModel.java:119)
    at mia.recommender.ch02.RecommenderIntro.main(RecommenderIntro.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 2 more
```

It seems to me that the the problem comes from FileDataModel.java, which belongs to this libary itself. How to trace back or analyze this error.

The example code is given as follows, which exactly is the one copied from the book. The line causing the trouble is

```
DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new File("intro.csv")); 


import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.*;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.neighborhood.*;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.*;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.similarity.*;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.model.*;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.neighborhood.*;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.recommender.*;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.similarity.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class RecommenderIntro {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new File("intro.csv")); 
    UserSimilarity similarity = new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity(model);
    UserNeighborhood neighborhood =
      new NearestNUserNeighborhood(2, similarity, model);
    Recommender recommender = new GenericUserBasedRecommender(
        model, neighborhood, similarity); 
    List<RecommendedItem> recommendations =
        recommender.recommend(1, 1); 
    for (RecommendedItem recommendation : recommendations) {
      System.out.println(recommendation);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not really anything to do with Mahout. You don't have all the libs it uses available to your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the SLF4J dependency is not installed/on the classpath:  slf4j-api.jar

See: http://www.slf4j.org/